# Создать функцию из reduce, аналогичную map

Tags: javascript, typescript, map

Всем привет! Дали подобное задание. Я его выполнил простым способом и все работает.

```
const mapReduce = (array) => {
   return array.reduce((collection, element) => {
      return [...collection, element];
   }, []);
};
```

Но в задании говорится следующее: Реализовать функцию со следующими сигнатурами

```
map<T, V>(callback: (element: T) => V, collection: T[]): V[]
```

Как это можно реализовать?
Я понимаю что <T, V> - это дженерики, для указания типа. Но не представляю как это использовать с reduce?

Comment: это точно javascript? не typescript?

Comment: Это TS, но реализацию можно и на JS, через JSDOC можно будет потом переправить

Comment: Насколько я вижу, всё что делает ваша первая функция это очень сложным способом копирует массив. И не вижу какое отношение она имеет к заданию.

Comment: "Но не представляю как это использовать с reduce" --- а зачем reduce если вам нужно сделать функцию аналогичную map? и даже метода назван map. Причём тут reduce? ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, для того чтобы показать, что все функции работы с массивом типа map, filter - можно реализовать с помощью reduce

Comment: Ну и попытайтесь сделать хоть что-нибудь. Покажите что вы хотите научится, а не пришли с просьбой «напишите за меня». Тут всё пишется за пять строчек кода.

Comment: @Alexey Ten ну вообще-то пытался. Уже второй день думаю. Не просил написать готовое решение, а можно просто дать наводку какую-нибудь или ссылку на статью, по которой можно будет понять данную тему.

Comment: Так что нужно сделать то? В чем задание?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko нужно сделать функционал map'a через функцию reduce с указанными сигнатурами

Comment: `const map = (cb, items) => items.reduce((acc, item) => ([ ...acc, cb(item) ]), [])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сигнатура

```
map<T, V>(callback: (element: T) => V, collection: T[]): V[]
```

указывает но следующее:

1. функция принимает два параметра: callback, collection
2. функция возвращает новый массив

Соответственно в код необходимо добавить один параметр

```
const mapReduce = (callback, collection) => {
```

тип элементов возвращаемого массива совпадает с типом, который возвращает callback, это говорит о том, что в результирующий массив идет результат вызова `callback`. Стоит обратить, что данная функция принимает один параметр, соответствующий элементу исходной коллекции.

Исходя из этого код может выглядеть так:

```
const mapReduce = (callback, collection) => {
   return collection.reduce((acc, element) => {
      return [...acc, callback(element)];
   }, []);
};
```

---

Также можно отметить, что размер конечного массива известен заранее и совпадает с размером исходного массива. Поэтому можно заранее создать массив нужного размера и просто заполнить его, не создавая новый массив на каждой итерации:

```
const mapReduce = (callback, collection) => {
   return collection.reduce((acc, element, index) => {
      acc[index] = callback(element);
      return acc;
   }, new Array(collection.length));
};
```

Comment: Можно начать с пустого массива и делать в него `push`. Формально второй вариант более правильный, т.к. сохраняет «дырки» в исходном массиве (как и настоящий `map`).

Comment: @Grundy моей проблемой оказалось то, что я не правильно представлял сигнатуры, вчера только столкнулся с дженериками, и поэтому предствлял 1 аргумент calback который возвращает V и еще коллекцию и не понимал как такое возможно... Спасибо огромное за разъяснение сигнатур.